# Facebook share button title "Redirects to..."

Tags: php, facebook, button, share

I am implementing share button on my website. I have correct meta tags for image, title, description and so on.
When a the user clicks on the share button, instead of the metatag title, he sees the following on the share popup: "Redirects to " and a url to my website and the article.

Any ideas what could be the problem? And again, I have correct og:title, og:description, og:url  tags on my page.

Comment: Add an example to it, please. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve